# join() method and The Complete Java Reference 9th Edition

Tags: java

```
// Using join() to wait for threads to finish.
class NewThread implements Runnable {
    String name; // name of thread
    Thread t;
    NewThread(String threadname) {
        name = threadname;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
        t.start(); // Start the thread
    }
    // This is the entry point for thread.
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
    }
}
class DemoJoin {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
        NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
        NewThread ob3 = new NewThread("Three");

        System.out.println("Thread One is alive: " + ob1.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: " + ob2.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: " + ob3.t.isAlive());
        // wait for threads to finish
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Thread One is alive: " + ob1.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: " + ob2.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: " + ob3.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

Hi, there. I have a problem with this peace of code from "The Complete Java Reference - 9th Edition". I get different output everytime I run this code.
Here's the example:

```
New thread: Thread[One,5,main]
New thread: Thread[Two,5,main]
New thread: Thread[Three,5,main]
One: 5
Thread One is alive: true
Thread Two is alive: true
Thread Three is alive: true
Waiting for threads to finish.
Two: 5
Three: 5
One: 4
Three: 4
Two: 4
One: 3
Two: 3
Three: 3
One: 2
Two: 2
Three: 2
One: 1
Three: 1
Two: 1
One exiting.
Two exiting.
Three exiting.
Thread One is alive: false
Thread Two is alive: false
Thread Three is alive: false
Main thread exiting.
```

The output in the book is:

```
 New thread: Thread[One,5,main]
 New thread: Thread[Two,5,main]
 New thread: Thread[Three,5,main]
 Thread One is alive: true
 Thread Two is alive: true
 Thread Three is alive: true
 Waiting for threads to finish.
 One: 5
 Two: 5
 Three: 5
 One: 4
 Two: 4
 Three: 4
 One: 3
 Two: 3
 Three: 3
 One: 2
 Two: 2
 Three: 2
 One: 1
 Two: 1
 Three: 1
 Two exiting.
 Three exiting.
 One exiting.
 Thread One is alive: false
 Thread Two is alive: false
 Thread Three is alive: false
 Main thread exiting.
```

Now, I understand how threads work, but I don't quite understand why do my new threads start at the concurrently with my main thread.Can anyone help me with that? Ty.

EDIT: Shouldn't the main thread run until join(), sleep() or some other famiiliar method, and then, when that method "happens", Thread::running should take the next one from the Ready queue?

EDIT: This code:

```
// Create a second thread.
class NewThread implements Runnable {
 Thread t;
 NewThread() {
 // Create a new, second thread
 t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
 System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
 t.start(); // Start the thread
 }
 // This is the entry point for the second thread.
 public void run() {
 try {
 for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
 System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
 }
 System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
 }
}

class ThreadDemo {
 public static void main(String args[ ] ) {
 new NewThread(); // create a new thread
 try {
 for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
 System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
 }
 System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
 }
}
```

always works the same. How come? It's the same stuff, second thread is start()-ed in constructor, yet this code gives the same result every time:

```
Child thread: Thread[Demo Thread,5,main]
Main Thread: 5
Child Thread: 5
Child Thread: 4
Main Thread: 4
Child Thread: 3
Child Thread: 2
Main Thread: 3
Child Thread: 1
Exiting child thread.
Main Thread: 2
Main Thread: 1
Main thread exiting.
```

Comment: That's what the `start()` method of a `Thread` does. It starts it concurrently. In that example, notice that `start()` is called in the `NewThread()` constructor. When you have concurrent things printing to output, they might be in different orders different times you run it.

Answer (score 2):

Because the new thread begins running as soon as `start()` is called.

The main thread creates the first thread and starts it. It is now a race between the main thread starting the other two threads and printing the wait message against the first thread starting it's countdown.

Who wins the race? Arbitrary and depends on hardware.